# Error message keeps coming before entering successful username and password in login.php

Tags: php, html, mysql, authentication

These are the codes of the website that I'm working on:

1) login.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
include("connection.php");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername = (isset($_POST['myusername']) ? $_POST['myusername'] : null);
$mypassword = (isset($_POST['mypassword']) ? $_POST['mypassword'] : null); 


// To protect MySQL injection
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername); 
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword); 
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername); 
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword); 

$qry = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name ='$myusername' AND user_password = '$mypassword'";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

$output = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
      if($count == 1) {
         $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
         $_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;
         header("location: foodline.php");
         exit();
      }
      else {
         echo "Invalid Username or Password";
      }
?>


<html>
   
   <head>
      <title>Login Page</title>
      
      <style type = "text/css">
         body {
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size:14px;
         }
         
         label {
            font-weight:bold;
            width:100px;
            font-size:14px;
         }
         
         .box {
            border:#666666 solid 1px;
         }
      </style>
      
   </head>
   
   <body bgcolor = "#FFFFFF">
 
      <div align = "center">
         <div style = "width:300px; border: solid 1px #333333; " align = "left">
            <div style = "background-color:#333333; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px;"><b>Login</b></div>
    
            <div style = "margin:30px">
               
               <form action = "" method = "post">
                  <label>UserName  :</label><input type = "text" name = "username" class = "box"/><br /><br />
                  <label>Password  :</label><input type = "password" name = "password" class = "box" /><br/><br />
                  <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/><br />
               </form>     
            </div>
    
         </div>
   
      </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

2) connection.php

```html
<?php
$mysql_hostname ="localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password ="";
$mysql_database = "foodline";

mysql_connect("$mysql_hostname", "$mysql_user", "$mysql_password") or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db("$mysql_database") or die("Could not connect the database".mysql_error());
?>
```

3) session.php

```html
<?php
   include('connection.php');
   session_start();
   
   $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];
   
   $ses_sql = mysql_query($user_check);
   
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($ses_sql);
   
   $login_session = $row['username'];
   
   if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user']))
   {
      header("location:foodline.php");
   }
?>
```

4) This is the output screen that I'm getting:
[Output Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsale.png)

The error message 'Invalid Username or Password' won't remove from above codes. Anything that I'm missing or anything that is done extra on the code?

Please help me!

Comment: the query (SELECT * FROM...) alone works?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get your question.

Answer (score 0):

You'd only want the PHP part to execute if your form has been submitted. Make use of `isset`.

Update your php with this.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("connection.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // username and password sent from form 
    $myusername = (isset($_POST['myusername']) ? $_POST['myusername'] : null);
    $mypassword = (isset($_POST['mypassword']) ? $_POST['mypassword'] : null); 


    // To protect MySQL injection
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername); 
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword); 
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername); 
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword); 

    $qry = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name ='$myusername' AND user_password = '$mypassword'";
    $result = mysql_query($qry);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    $output = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
          if($count == 1) {
             $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
             $_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;
             header("location: foodline.php");
             exit();
          }
          else {
             echo "Invalid Username or Password";
          }
}
?>
```

Now, your php will only execute if the form has been submitted.

Update

```
"SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name ='" . $myusername . "' AND user_password = '" . $mypassword . "'";
```

Comment: That was quick! Thank you!! But now the problem I'm facing is that I've not been redirected to the main page 'foodline.php' after I hit the username and password!

Comment: Yes, I do. Don't know why it isn't redirecting to the main page... I hope my codes are correct!

Comment: What does `var_dump($result)` gives you? Place this line after your query line.

Comment: Then it's a problem with your query. I've updated my answer. Use my updated query.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name ='" . $myusername . "' AND user_password = '" . $mypassword . "'";

I think there's a problem after, user_name=, one inverted comma is extra...

Comment: Yeah, I have tried. Not is happening. Is it possible that the database is not reacting because I am refreshing the login page many times? Trying to redirect again and again won't affect anything right?

Comment: If you're not getting positive result from your query, then it's a problem with your query.